# Error al llamar funcion React Native

Tags: react-native

tengo la funcion SideMenu, y la quiero llamar dentro de mi componente Header, los dos se encuentran en la misma clase...

Aqui adjunto mi funcion SideMenu :

```js
const SideMenu = () => {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style ={{flex : 1 }}>
                <View style = {{
                    height : 150,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <Text>MotherF*cker</Text>
                    <ScrollView>
                        <List>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Text>gfdsgfdsg</Text>
                            </ListItem>
                        </List>
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
```

Aqui tengo la funcion Header

```js
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header component={SideMenu}/>
            <Text>hehe</Text>

            <Button
            title = "Go!"
            onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('Detalle', { title : '432354', user_name:'Josefina'})}
            />
        </View>

    )
};
```

Comment: Y cual es el error?

Comment: El error es el siguiente: fn is not a function”?...pero si que es una funcion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que *SideMenu* no es una función sino un componente. y deberías llamarlo así:

```
import { sideMenu } from".../tuRuta"

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (

        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header component={<SideMenu/>}/>
            <Text>hehe</Text>

            <Button
            title = "Go!"
            onPress= {() => navigation.navigate('Detalle', { title : '432354', user_name:'Josefina'})}
            />
        </View>

    )
};
```

Recuerda que tienes que exportar el componente de *sideMenu*:

```
export const SideMenu = () => {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style ={{flex : 1 }}>
                <View style = {{
                    height : 150,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center'
                }}>
                    <Text>MotherF*cker</Text>
                    <ScrollView>
                        <List>
                            <ListItem>
                                <Text>gfdsgfdsg</Text>
                            </ListItem>
                        </List>
                    </ScrollView>
                </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
```